# How to convert SQL server 24 hour time string to 12 hour datetime data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a column named `origdttime` that is a text field. I would like to convert this to a 12 hour time field.  The values of the field are`hh:mi:ss.mmm` i.e. `06:46:00.000` I would like for this time to appear as `06:46 AM`

I am using the statement `CONVERT(varchar(15), origdttime ,8) AS [time]` however it is returning the exact same format and values.

What needs to be adjusted to return my desired output?

Comment: First thing I suggest is changing the schema to hold a time value when you want to store a time value. Using a text field to hold time values will no doubt  cause problems in the future.

Comment: it is not my schema to change, I would like to extract the data as time.

Answer (score 7):

Try ....

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST('06:46:00.000' AS TIME),100)
```

Result:

```
6:46AM
```

---

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST('17:46:00.000' AS TIME),100)
```

Result:

```
5:46PM
```

Answer (score 2):

While performance is not always great using `FORMAT()` if you are on SQL-Server 2012 + it is convenient option especially for smaller data sets etc.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (TimeAsString VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('06:46:00.000'),('17:46:00.000')

SELECT
   TimeAsString
   ,FORMAT(CAST(TimeAsString as DATETIME), 'hh:mm tt')
FROM
    @Table
```